# Handle phpmailer connect() fail error

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a payroll CSV import feature that creates new users and send users welcome email with phpmailer, notifying account for them have been created.

Issue:

Blockquote

For a few (about 10 in 500) users, I have `SMTP connect() failed` error, which those users won't receive email.

What I've done:
Using a loop to attempt maximum 10 times

Question:
What would be the best approach to make sure all users will receive an email, instead of looping 10 or 100, or infinite times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use PHPMailer for this purpose, it's not an MTA (which is what you're asking it to be). Use PHPMailer to generate messages and submit them to a local mail server (a proper MTA, like Postfix), have the mail server deal with queuing and retrying, then handle the bounces when they come back.